# Conditional Compile - Implementation Alternatives

Tags: c, cross-platform, portability, conditional-compilation

I was looking for a good resource that provides a discussion on best practices for conditional compilation and cross-plattform portability for C projects.

For example:

Writing a network library that (depending on the underlying platform) either uses TCP or SCTP. The usual approach would probably be to define a common API specification and let the makefile decide to compile the correct implementation.

I cannot imagine that conditional compilation using MACROS and code duplication is a good idea here (since such a network implementation is mostly the same, with differing SEND and RECEIVE primitives).

Does anybody have good suggestions or a good resource discussing best practices to these problems?

Thanks for your input!

Comment: is there something wrong with the usual approach?
Have you tried to look-up any existing examples of other libraries using this approach?

Comment: the problem I encountered with using macros for such problems is that (if used more frequently) they make testing very cumbersome.

Answer (score 0):

Macros are good if you limit them to very few places. Example:

```
#if defined LINUX
#   include "linux/mylib.h"
#elif defined WINDOWS
#   include "windows/mylib.h"
#else
#   error "unsupported platform!"
#endif
```

Comment: true, but how would you share the common code between both libs, which is equivalent on both platforms? Probably introduce one level of header indirection?